# What is CORS default policy

Tags: cors

What is CORS default policy if it's not explicitly implemented by the Web Server ?

Comment: That's explained quite clearly in the second paragraph of the Wikipedia article on [Cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), isn't it?

Comment: I see. They say AJAX requests are forbidden by default, but I saw in other articles, that what is generally forbidden is read request content, and not sending request. That's why asked this question to get a definitive answer.

Comment: @Sidahmed "I saw in articles" - then link to those articles.

Answer (score 2):

Without [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS), [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) (SO) applies.  CORS is used to relax SO - typically on an as-needed basis, and only when deemed safe to do so by the admin of the site that is sharing resources cross-origin.